# What is the difference between "mesmerise by" and "mesmerise with"

Tags: word-usage, difference

How can we use the word 'mesmerised' in Active Voice?

1. The magician mesmerised the audience with his performance with a lion.
2. The magician mesmerised the audience by his performance with a lion.

Mesmerize by / with.

Eg- The thief mesmerised the child with/ by a fancy toy.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to devise a rule that suits all verbs and circumstances. But I would use **by** to designate an *action* and **with** to designate a thing.

> She entertained the kids by *telling* them a story.
>
> She entertained the kids with *a story*.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as much about "**mesmerize by/with**" as it is about "**with/by his performance**":

If we use a different verb, for instance "**surprise**" we get:

1. The magician surprised the audience with his performance with a lion.
2. The magician surprised the audience by his performance with a lion.

We can clearly see that the 1st is correct while the second one is also correct but would be even better with a present participle.

Comment: So, should it be framed- The magician mesmerised the audience by performing with a lion.???? And sentence number 1 sounds appropriate...right?

Comment: @Ayesha Either your example or **by showing his perfomance with a lion**.

Answer (score 1):

The verb **mesmerize** is often used in the passive with the preposition *by* not *with* because it means to have someone's attention completely so that they cannot think of anything else.
 However, you can use other verbs in active and serve the same meaning like *capture, captivate, fascinate, ...*

Comment: Even I thought the same thing... but when I checked the Merriam Webster dictionary, the meaning given was- to hold the attention/ attract or amaze someone... so I thought, 'mesmerise' could be used in Active voice.